# Pulling a specific field with php out of a xml upload

Tags: php, xml

I've been trying to get the id field to pull and have no idea where I'm going wrong. The rest of the data pulls correctly but I'm trying to add something new to some existing code and everything I've tried hasn't worked. Below is my XML and the PHP code I've been working off of.

I haven't worked with a combo of xml and php before so I could really use a push in the right direction.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enterprise>
   <person>
        <sourcedid>
            <source>Spirit Awards</source>
            <id>SP8675309</id>
        </sourcedid>
        <userid>...</userid>
        <name>
            <fn>...</fn>
        </name>
        <email>...</email>
    </person>
```

PHP code:

```
function get_userid(){
    return $this->uid;
}
function __construct($xmlData){
    $this->uid = (string)$xmlData->id;
}
```

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SimpleXML`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) makes this ... well ... simple. The XML you've posted is missing a closing `</enterprise>` tag. Assuming the XML you're actually parsing includes the closing tag, consider:

```
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enterprise>
   <person>
        <sourcedid>
            <source>Spirit Awards</source>
            <id>SP8675309</id>
        </sourcedid>
        <userid>...</userid>
        <name>
            <fn>...</fn>
        </name>
        <email>...</email>
    </person>
</enterprise>
';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$var = (string) $xml->person->sourcedid->id;
echo $var; // outputs: SP8675309
```

Comment: Yeah I just copied part of the file. It does have a closing tag, I just copied part of the file for an example that I'm uploading into the page. I'm going to try this now and see if I can get it to work. Thanks!